SQLite GROUP_CONCAT with INNER JOIN
I'm trying to imlplement a system of tags in a project of mine.

Each 'quote' may have many tags, and each 'tag' may be used in a number of quotes

Thus, I have three tables, 'quotes', 'tags' and 'tag_instances'.
I'm trying to make a query that returns details about a quote, including a string with all the tags in.
This was my first attempt at making it work:
SELECT
    quotes.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.title, ', ') AS quote_tags
FROM quotes
INNER JOIN tag_instances ON quotes.id = tag_instances.quote 
INNER JOIN tags ON tag_instances.tag = tags.id

However, this results in tag_list being a string concatenating all the tags with an instance. I'd rather just have the tags with an instance on the quote for that row.
I'm not particuarly familiar with SQLite, but I do know that in postgres, it'd be done like this:
SELECT 
    quotes.*
    STRING_AGG(tags.title, ', ') AS quote_tags
FROM quotes
INNER JOIN tag_instances ON quotes.id = tag_instances.quote
INNER JOIN tags ON tag_instances.tag = tag.id

Any advice translating the postgres flavoured sql to sqlite falvoured would be welcome.

You're missing GROUP BY clause to form the groups , e.g.: GROUP BY quotes.id, quotes.text(or whatever). SQLite allows you allows you to use bare columns in an aggregate query that don't appear within an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. The value of such columns in the result set will be any of the values that form the aggregate.

Did you mean something like this?
  quotes.id, quotes.quote, quotes.author, quotes.date,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tags.title, ', ') AS quote_tags
FROM quotes
INNER JOIN tag_instances ON quotes.id = tag_instances.quote 
INNER JOIN tags ON tag_instances.tag = tags.id;
GROUP BY quotes.id, quotes.preamble, quotes.quote, quotes.author, quotes.date, quotes.confirmed_date, quotes.message_id

This query doesn't fix the problem, all the tags with an entry in tag_instances are still concatenated into one string.

Maybe you should add some sample data and desired output to your question, because I struggle to understand what's the problem.

I found a way to get the desired result using a subquery:
SELECT
  quotes.*,
  (
    SELECT tags.title FROM tags
    INNER JOIN tag_instances ON tag_instances.tag = tags.id
    WHERE tag_instances.quote = quotes.id
  ) as quote_tags
FROM quotes

